# github actions. fatal: could not read Password for 'https://***@github.com': No such file or directory

Tags: javascript, github, github-actions

When I push my code, it says an error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJVQs.png)
Here is my yml.English is not my native language.
I can't generate SSH tokens in GitHub Actions

```js
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout Code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Install Node.js, NPM and Yarn
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
          node-version: 12.18.3
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: |
            npm i
    - name: Electron Build
      run: |
            npm install hexo-cli -g
            hexo g
    - name: Push Build
      run: |
            git config --global user.name "${{secrets.U_NAME}}"
            git config --global user.email "${{secrets.U_EMAIL}}"
            git config --global user.password "${{secrets.PASSWORD}}"
            git clone "https://${{secrets.GH_TOKEN}}@${{secrets.GH_REF}}"
            Copy-Item "public\*" "yolkpie.github.io\" -Recurse -Force
            cd ./yolkpie.github.io
            git add .
            git commit -m 'travis-ci auto build yolk-blog'
            git config remote.origin.url "https://${{secrets.GH_TOKEN}}@${{secrets.GH_REF}}"
            git push origin "${{secrets.P_BRANCH}}"
            echo Hello, world123!
```

I want the code to push properly

Comment: Maybe try authenticating with ssh

Comment: Is `GH_TOKEN` a PAT (Personal Access Token) for that repo that you're pushing to?

Comment: I can't generate SSH tokens in GitHub Actions. yes, it is